# Why do empty structs in C++20 do not have implicit spaceship operator?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Motivation: sometimes I use std::variant to implement "fancy" enum where some enum states can carry state.

Now if I want to use the `<=>` for my variant it requires that my empty structs have defined <=>.
That seems a bit weird to me since if type has 0 bits of state all instances of that type are same.

Full [example](https://godbolt.org/z/P66K4v):

```
#include <compare>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct Off{
    // without this the code does not compile
    auto operator<=>(const Off& other) const = default;
};

struct Running{
    int rpm=1000;
    auto operator<=>(const Running& other) const = default;
};

using EngineState = std::variant<Off, Running>;

int main()
{
    EngineState es1, es2;
    es1<=>es2;
}
```

Comment: ... why should empty types suddenly have behavior that isn't specified in their definitions?

Comment: @NicolBolas why do floats have <=> in C++20, when for 40 years before in C++ there was no <=>

Comment: why does it matter if the struct is empty? The difference is that once you declare the operator and if you dont then it isnt declared.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "*why do floats have <=> in C++20, when for 40 years before in C++ there was no <=>*" Because floats are comparable, and have been for 40 years. `<=>` is just a different way of saying "comparable". Empty classes have never been comparable by default.

Comment: I think you are a little bit too preoccupied about " since if type has 0 bits of state all instances of that type are same.". Comparsion in not necessarily about comparing the bits and bytes of objects. You can have 0 byte objects such that for any `x` and `y` the relation `x < y` is `true`

Comment: @NicolBolas I have to admit that this question was a mistake. Not that I like the current situation, but my phrasing of it was dumb/wrong. I was focusing on why Empty does not have default operator <=> but that would be a wrong fix for this issue. 
My question should have been why <=> of variant(or any struct/class containing Empty) is not smart enough(using compiler internal check like std::is_empty) to skip comparing empty struct. 
Too late to edit the question now since it totally changes the meaning of the question, will probably open new one later.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 see my previous comment, also nobody would prevent you from having insane <=> if you want to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The defaulted comparison operator is opt-in, not opt-out.

If it was opt-out, then it could turn code that would not compile into code that compiles with some unknown meaning. The standard committee tries to maintain backwards compatibility as much as possible.

Comment: Isn't that what every new thing does? `auto p = "Hello";` didn't used to compile, now it does with some completely unrelated meaning.

Comment: And what's the point in preserving code that doesn't compile anyway? It's not like there are code bases out there with lots of code that is important, but doesn't compile. I am not saying implicit `<=>` would be good, but I don't think this explanations it.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: "*And what's the point in preserving code that doesn't compile anyway?*" Because it lets you know that the code you've written is nonsense and you should fix it. If the compiler makes a guess, it could guess *wrong*. And that's worse than a compile error; that's silent agreement with broken code. Many problems in C++ could be fixed if the compiler stopped guessing your intent.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree with that point. Most implicit things are to be used carefully. But that has nothing to with backwards compatibility as this answer seems to claim.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this ultimately comes down to this: what does it mean for a type to be "comparable"?

A type that is comparable is, first and foremost, a type which carries a *value*. Objects of such types carry a value that is meaningful in some sense.

Your example is one such case. Essentially, you are using `variant` and `Off` to augment the value-state of `Running` with an alternative value. I would have used `optional<Running>` myself, but whatever. `Off` is a type which legitimately has a value within your problem space. Its value being "not running".

This is not the case for most empty object types. `std::in_place_t` has no meaningful "value" by any definition of that term. It's a tag used to dispatch in-place construction calls to constructors of certain types. Asking to compare one instance to another makes no sense.

Yet you want to make it comparable by default.

There are a *lot* of stateless types that are not used in a value-oriented way. Tags for dispatching to overload sets, types used to provide object-based access to global resources, etc. That's not to say that there are no value-oriented empty types. But there are enough of them that unilaterally declaring that all of them ought to be comparable by default seems very strange.

Also, being value-oriented is a necessary condition for comparability, but it is not alone *sufficient*. We don't have default comparability for types that are *clearly* value-oriented.

Aggregate types have all public members, so there's nothing stopping anyone from shoving any value in them at any time. They are *clearly* value-oriented.

Yet aggregate types are not comparable by default. Nor should they be. Not everything which could hypothetically be compared *should* be compared.

Even if a particular collection of values could be ordered, does it make sense to *permit* them to be ordered? That depends on the collection. If I have a 2D point type, it could be ordered. But *should* it? I can understand equality testing, but full-on comparability? You can define it, but is such a comparison ever *meaningful*?

That's a question only the creator of the type can answer. Therefore, we force the creator of types to ask for what they want.

And having no members is just a special case of having some public members.

Comment: note about optional: I only used 2 state variant in example, IRL it can be 5 states, 3 of them tags, 2 with some data...